# Return highest number found in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects.  The objects have a property called `level` that is a string which contains a number and is in consistent format.

I am trying to find the highest number and return just that one but I seem to be blocked as far as how to proceed from my current code.

Here is a fiddle to my current code:  http://jsfiddle.net/6sXYR/

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        color: 'blue',
        level: 'L1'
    },
    {
        color: 'red',
        level: 'L1'
    },
    {
        color: 'green',
        level: 'L2'
    },
    {
        color: 'yellow',
        level: 'L2'
    },
    {
        color: 'purple',
        level: 'L3'
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log( myArray[i].level.substring(1,2) );
};
```

The result I am trying to get is to return just the number '3' from the example above.  The highest number may not always be in the last object in the array, but it will always be in the format of L#.

Comment: do you mean `#` stands for ***just*** numbers in `L#`? if so just replace `L` with empty string, then you have the number part.

Comment: @KingKing Yes.  The `#` could be any number, but the `L` part will always be L and come before the number.  So `L1` and `L101` are possible.  I think I need to compare the numbers to determine which is the highest but I seem to be stuck on that.

Comment: you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/6sXYR/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (**http://jsfiddle.net/QQv7E/**):

```
var highestNum=0;
for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    var num = parseInt(myArray[i].level.substring(1));
    if (num > highestNum) {
        highestNum = num;
    }
}
console.log(highestNum);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As King King mentioned in a comment to your question, if there's no other particular reason to put your levels in this format: `L#`,
you might as well only put the numbers in there (in `int` format, not `string`).

The result is that this line:
`var num = parseInt(myArray[i].level.substring(1));`
becomes this line:
`var num = myArray[i].level;`

That strips away both the `substring()` and the `parseInt()` function, making your code quite a bit more effective.

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H8X8x/**

Comment: I was able to use your update!  Thank you so much, I really learned a lot from the discussion and answers!

Answer (score 3):

Yet another option using [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, myArray.map(function (e) {
    return +e.level.substr(1); // Using substr to allows values like L10 etc.
})));
```

Comment: and what if the number is more than one digit long?

Comment: @myfunkyside Fair point. I hadn't considered that because of the question. We'd use `substr(1)` instead of `substring(1,2)` like in your answer. +1 from me btw.

Comment: `substring(1)` is also OK, the second index is optional, without it it means getting string from the start index to the end.

Comment: @DanielCook - is this answer faster/lighter than mine? (I'm genuinely interested)

Comment: @myfunkyside I've not tested it but looks like yours is faster, this is just shorter.

Comment: @myfunkyside I'd assume yours is faster due to only iterating through the array once, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @KingKing - do you know if one of the two `substr` and `substring` is faster than the other in a case like this? I Always wondered which one I could use best in such cases

Comment: @myfunkyside I'm not sure, I think `substr(1)` and `substring(1)` are the same in performance.

Comment: @myfunkyside Even if the speed does vary, the difference is [trivial](http://jsperf.com/substr-vs-substring).

Comment: @DanielCook - Cool, thanks for that test! And thank you both for your answers. (And `substring(1)` does appear to be a tad faster, I honestly thought `substr` would be.. learned something again)

Comment: just made a test about the use of `Math.max` and the traditional for-loop, as expected using `Math.max` is about 60-70% slower http://jsperf.com/long-code-vs-short-code

Comment: Wow, that's quite a bit indeed

Comment: Thanks for the update and the discussion.  I had not seen the `.map` before!

Answer (score 1):

you may want to account for possible null values for the 'level' property.

```
var maxL= 0, next;

myArray.forEach(function(itm){
    next= (itm.level || 'L0').slice(1);
    if(maxL-next<0) maxL= +next;
});
console.log(maxL)
```

// maxL= 3

Answer (score 0):

Using bubble sort which is ok for very small set you can do something like this:

```
var _sorted = myArray.sort(function(a,b) {
 return b.level.substring(1,2) - a.level.substring(1,2);
});
console.log(_sorted[0]);
```

Now note that this resolves partially your problem since if you had more than one L3 only the first one would be picked. Hopefully that gets you started on the right path.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was thinking off but was having trouble with some data that had more than 1 number which was the highest return.  Like multiple instances of `3`.

Comment: the number can be longer than one digit.. better remove that restiction

Comment: The statements which i wrote are almost same like this one why the hell i got -1 :(

Answer (score -1):

```
function sortDSC(a,b) {
  if (a.level < b.level)
     return 1;
  if (a.level > b.level)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}    
myArray.sort(sortDSC);   
var maxL = myArray[0].level.substring(1, myArray[0].level.length);
console.log(maxL);//3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dp7yN/